# black boxes flickering on the screen on tap

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I am trying to make an html game where in the player throws a ball or something upon tapping the screen or "the person holding the game" in the game.

As soon as I touch the player,there is a black screen(like a border around the player) which flicks for a second and disappears.

I noticed this issue on both iPhone and an android phone.

What might be the issue with this?

edit:Added some code.The `chucker` has an image and whenever I tap it,a black box flickers around the image for a second

```
<div id="chucker"  onclick="getId(event);"></div>

function getId(e)
{
    if(e.target.id == "game_container" || e.target.id == "chucker" )
    {
        rotateTheAngleMarker(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: We'll need code to debug this Harsha - paste some in and we'll take a gander...

Comment: @Neurofluxation Might the reason be onClick?